# Hosting Bootstrap/Jquery/HTML5Shiv locally breaks site in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I have a site that I built using bootstrap and it worked just fine in **IE8**.  Then I decided that in order to make my site load a little faster, i was going to stop bulling the various `.js` and `.css` files for `bootstrap/jquery/html5shiv/etc` from other servers and host them locally.  Doing that broke my site in IE8. In IE8, I get something that sort of resembles the mobile version.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  I should be able to host all of these files locally, right?

Here is what I have in my  tag originally that works:

```
   <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->



<link href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <link href="/css/ffnv4.4.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
     if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
        var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");
        msViewportStyle.appendChild(
            document.createTextNode(
                "@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}"
            )
        );
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].
            appendChild(msViewportStyle);
    }
</script>
```

And here's the new code that doesn't work:

```
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->



<link href="<? echo CONTENT_SERVER; ?>/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="<? echo CONTENT_SERVER; ?>/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="<? echo CONTENT_SERVER; ?>/js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->



        <link href="<? echo CONTENT_SERVER; ?>/css/ffnv4.4.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="<? echo CONTENT_SERVER; ?>/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="<? echo CONTENT_SERVER; ?>/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
        var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");
        msViewportStyle.appendChild(
            document.createTextNode(
                "@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}"
            )
        );
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].
            appendChild(msViewportStyle);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `respond.js` isn't being loaded. I'm guessing you're trying to load it over `http` but you aren't using a web server...

Comment: @ChrisHardie I absolutely am using a web server.

Comment: and you are positive that your file paths are correct?

Comment: Do your developer tools note any errors?

Answer (score -1):

Because Twitter Bootstarp 3 and jquery version 2  dont has dropped IE8 support.

Comment: This isn't right. It works if I use the remotely hosted files.

Comment: Bootstrap v3 DOES support IE8: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-browsers